# Error deploying Qt application on OS X

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, macdeployqt

I'm trying to deploy a **Qt application** on **OS X** using `macdeployqt`:

`macdeployqt MyApplication.app -dmg`

The application uses the **Qwt library**, which is being included in the **PRO** file as follows:

`macx: QWT_ROOT = /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0
include ( $${QWT_ROOT}/features/qwt.prf )`

When I run the `macdeployqt` command I get the following error message:

`ERROR: no file at "/Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt"`

I'm not sure but it seems the deployment step is looking for the Qwt library on the wrong path, for example:

`"/Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt"`

When it should be:

`"/Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt"`

How can I solve it?

Comment: As a workaround it is possible to create the directory `sudo mkdir -p /Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt.framework/Versions/6/` and make a symply bridge as virtual link `ln -s /usr/local/qwt-6.1.3/lib/qwt.framework/Versions/Current/qwt /Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt` as explained [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/83121/error-deploying-qt-application-on-os-x/13). Note: I'm not sure if it solves the problem because I had other issues, but that error message disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have uninstalled other qt versions using `brew list`, `brew remove qt` and `brew remove qt5`. I also noted that I had pyqt installed (and I was not using it), so I also remove it using `brew remove pyqt`.

Then, I have reinstalled **Qt 5.3.2** and had other issues:

`Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.`

Which was solved changing the `isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcrun 2>/dev/null")))` command from the `Qt_install_folder/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf` file to `isEmpty($$list($$system("/usr/bin/xcrun -find xcodebuild 2>/dev/null")))`, as explained here: [Qt Creator - Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728905/qt-creator-project-error-xcode-not-set-up-properly-you-may-need-to-confirm-t)

and

`Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'`

That was solved by changing the `QtPath/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri` from `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.8` to `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12`, as explained here: [Error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8)

So, I run the command from my **Qt** directory:

```
/Users/kuser/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt MyApplication.app -dmg
```

and it worked.

I found these solutions in comments from the following question:

[Qt5 cannot find platform plugins Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988129/qt5-cannot-find-platform-plugins-mac-os-x)

**Note**: this does not solve the `macdeployqt` error directly, but as it is part of the Qt installation, reinstalling it solved my problem.