# Deploying a Qt application on Mac: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa

I'm attempting to deploy a Qt application in a portable manner, and I'm somewhat stuck on the plugins deployment, and the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html) isn't as clear as I was hoping.

At first, I started with macdeployqt, but I get the following message:

```
WARNING: Could not find any external Qt frameworks to deploy in "Utility.app" 
WARNING: Perhaps macdeployqt was already used on "Utility.app" ? 
WARNING: If so, you will need to rebuild "Utility.app" before trying again.
```

I checked versions, as suggested in [Qt5 cannot find platform plugins Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988129/qt5-cannot-find-platform-plugins-mac-os-x), but I don't see any evidence that I'm having similar issues (versions).

So, I started working on doing things manually, and I managed to get things working on my computer after copying over the necessary frameworks (those pointed out by otool -L), and removing the LC_RPATH entry that pointed to my local Qt installation.

However, I'm having issues with the plugins: if I have no plugins bundled in the application, it works locally, but not on anyone else's machine.  If I bundle libqcocoa.dylib in Utilities.app/Contents/plugins/platforms, then I get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Abort trap: 6

Particularly curious, since I did not copy the minimal or offscreen platform plugins...

I've also tried to set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to "../plugins/platforms" in the build steps, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  I've also played with several different settings in the qt.conf file, to no avail.

I've been chasing several different solutions for this for a while now, but feel free to .  Surely, I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you check whether you were trying to deploy a debug build of your application VS a release ? By the way, which version of Qt are you using ?

Comment: I'm most certainly deploying in release mode.  I'm on version 5.9.2 of Qt.

Comment: How did you install Qt ?

Comment: Hi, did you fix this eventually?

Comment: Unfortunately no, though I might come back to it and see if I can fix it.  It's on the back-burner for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path to Qt frameworks for qlibcocoa plugin inside application bundle with `install_name_tool`, like this:

> install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
>   MyApp.app/Contents/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib

libqcocoa.dylib depends on QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport.
Them all supposed to be in MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks.

libqcocoa.dylib supposed to be in
MyApp.app/Contents/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib

This works for me.